# Can "most of which" be used in the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-starts, is-it-a-rule, is-it-a-sentence

Just out of curiosity I would like to ask. By searching through the web I could not find an answer yet.

Can "most of which" be used in the beginning of a sentence? Here is an example of a sentence for which I would like to know whether I can make two out of it.

> Numerous articles were published on the topic of "Self-Assmebled Monolayers", most of which indicate that isocyanide binds through its terminal carbon atom.

Comment: As the cleverly contrived answers below show, your title question must be answered 'Yes'. However, you seem to be asking whether _Numerous articles were published on the topic of "Self-Assmebled Monolayers". Most of which indicate that isocyanide binds through its terminal carbon atom._ is acceptable. The second part has now been converted to a _sentence fragment_ rather than a true sentence. Most people nowadays accept that the careful use of sentence fragments is acceptable, even advantageous on occasion. But not, for stylistic reasons, in technical writing. As Colin Fine says.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. "Which" (used in this way) always refers to something (or some things) referenced earlier in the same sentence.

To split the example sentence, I would say:

> ...Self-Assembled Monolayers." **Most of the articles** indicate that..."

Or even just:

> ...Self-Assembled Monolayers." **Most indicate** that...

---

EDIT: The other use of "which" is not as a referent to something in a sentence (similar in some ways to a pronoun, though a totally different thing), but a "question word":

> Which actor would you choose for the role?

The two meanings are different and the rule I gave above for the former does not apply in the slightest to the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You say you didn't understand most of my arguments?  Most of which arguments did you fail to understand?

Answer (score 1):

This is not uncommon in some kinds of writing (for example, journalism, or fiction). An example from the British National Corpus:

> All of which is surely good for the future of British tennis. (Tennis World, 1992)

But it is best avoided in an academic paper.

Answer (score 0):

Not without forming a dependent-word sentence fragment.

In your example, the pronoun *which* refers to the articles that were published.  If you want to break it up into two sentences, you should rephrase the second half.

> Of these articles, most indicate ...

or

> Most of the articles indicate ...

Personally, I find the sentence perfectly fine as-is.

Comment: 'A run-on is a sentence in which two or more independent clauses (i.e., complete sentences) are joined without appropriate punctuation or conjunction.' [Wikipedia] You say 'Not without forming a run-on sentence.' This implies 'Yes, if you form a run-on sentence'. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: I stand corrected.  All my life I've considered sentences with missing/incomplete subjects to be run-ons.  Thank you!

Comment: It's worth finding Nordquist's articles titled _sentence fragments_ and _crots_. He almost always lists conflicting views (on terminology, analysis and acceptability) and gives a balanced overview here.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the sense you're using it.

You could ask, "Most of *which* containers are filled?"

- meaning: "Which of these containers are *mostly* filled?"

-or-

"Most of *which* group of candidates is qualified?"

- meaning: "Which group has the majority of qualified candidates?"

But the former examples are awkward,(besides being questions) and you'd be better understood using the latter.